# "Not able to" vs. "unable to"

Tags: word-choice, negation, prefixes, negative-prefixes

Which phrase is more suitable to convey one's inability to do something — "not able to" or "unable to"? For example,

> - not able to join the meeting
> - unable to join the meeting

Comment: Either, both seem natural to me as a native speaker, though I may lean slightly towards "unable"

Comment: For example: I'm not able to come to a conclusion as to which is better since I am unable to decide which I use more often.

Comment: To my ears, unable is more fitting for short-lived circumstances. I'm unable to answer the phone right now. I'm not able to come to the party on Friday. Nah, after I think about it, it sounds about the same. Actually, if I think about it some more, it's not quite the same.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, _not able_ really throws me off, and I was quite surprised when I started moderating stackoverflow.com and found out that (seemingly) native English speakers tend to use _not able_ rather than _unable_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I interpret the sentences in different ways.

*"He was unable to join the meeting"* I read as, "he" was unable to join the meeting because of scheduling conflicts, or for reasons that made him decline participation in advance.

While I read *"He was not able to join the meeting"* as, "he" got held up in traffic or some other unforeseen situation prevented him from joining the meeting as he had planned.

I'm not sure there's any formal validity to this.

Comment: I’d say this is an _optional_ distinction, one that _can_ be made, but must not necessarily be made. If it is made, however, I agree with the distribution you describe. If I have no specific context, I would not necessarily infer scheduling conflicts or traffic jams from either version; but if I have a scheduling conflict, I would be more likely to say ‘I’m unable’, and if I’m stuck in traffic, I’d be more likely to say ‘I’m not able’ (or even more likely, ‘I won’t be able’).

Comment: One is "I could but won't bc my priorities are different", the other signifies literal impossibility.

Comment: Then what about a situation: "_We may be unable to catch the error."_ vs. 
_"We may not be able to catch the error."_ vs. _"We may be not able to catch the error."_? Is there an additional distinction there (for _may not_ case)?

Answer (score 1):

I think, 'Unable' denotes internal cause or inability and 'not able' external constraints.

Comment: Hello, Praveen. Have you any authoritative support for this view? It's not a distinction I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

I try to think of it as unsuccessful vs. not successful. 
"Not successful" is more general, whereas "unsuccessful" implies there is a set goal that was not accomplished. Or is it unaccomplished? And I'm not really sure how this applies to "able". Maybe I should take more English courses...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to attend the meeting. Here it implies some or other reason is the cause.I am unable to lift 100kg. It is purely inability of the person.

Comment: Why do you think this? I don't think that "not able" means the cause is external...

Answer (score -4):

Not able :not of permanent nature.    Unable   :most likely of permanent nature.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please take a moment to find upvoted answers to see the type of answer this site is looking for. We also provide [help on answering questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers should ideally include some sort of independent corroboration, [correctly referenced](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/18696). Don't forget, too, that you can edit existing posts to improve them; you don't usually need to post more than one answer.

Comment: What evidence do you have for these meanings? I don't think they are correct.